# Sliding Notification bar in java (a la Firefox)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, notifications, notification-bar

I would like to implement a sliding notification bar as the one in Firefox or IE for my java application. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I'm sure someone out there has already done it and is willing to share.
Do you know any open-source implementation of this in java/swing?

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in [Swing Hacks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009070) called "Slide Notes Out from the Taskbar" that seems pretty close to what you want (there's a [preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=oNbFfcyAtv4C&pg=PA240&dq=%22Swing+hacks%22+%22slide+notes+out+from+the+taskbar%22) on Google's Book Search at the moment).

The code is freely available from the [official O'Reilly Swing Hacks page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009076/), under "examples."  Not sure what the license is, but it's worth a look (Chapter 6, hack 46).  At any rate, Swing Hacks is a worthy purchase at ~$20.

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to do it is to use [Swing TrayIcon API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html). That would probably be the most convenient way too :)