# Good open-source Swing/Java component for doing MSN-like popup notifications

Tags: java, swing, components, notifications, msn

I am looking for a good open-source Java component for implementing popup notifications in a Swing desktop application.

The component should be able to function like the ones commonly seen in instant messaging applications such as MSN Messenger, so that just as someone sends you a message, a little ontop window slides up from the right bottom corner of the screen and fades out after a few seconds.

I've been Googling for it for quite some time now but I just can't believe that no ones has ever written something like that in Java/Swing.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you talking about the little popups that come up from the little dock/icon set next to the clock in Windows?  Because that is very OS specific - for instance, os X doesn't have anything like that metaphor really.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal, but it could be coming from within the main application frame corner as well.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290210/sliding-notification-bar-in-java-a-la-firefox

Answer (score 2):

How about using the SystemTray and TrayIcon classes in Java 6?

Answer (score 0):

We had to implement that one in Windows ourselves.  We used a JNI wrapper to a dll that would allow us to pop the window up on top of other applications.  The fade is something that isn't available yet, but I believe it will be included in Java 7.