# How to create a notification in swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, notifications

Using Java and Swing, is there any (convenient) way to create a notification? 
By notification, I mean something like:

[image: this]
, [image: this]
<sub>(source: [maketecheasier.com](http://images.maketecheasier.com/2010/01/kfirefox-notify-indexed.png))</sub>
, 
or 
[image: this]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/library/media/1086/malaysia/windows/images/windows-vista/quick-start/screenshot_activatewarning.jpg))</sub>

(Is there a more correct term for that?). It would be nice if it worked cross-platform, but I'm mainly concerned with it working under Ubuntu with Gnome. If at all possible, I would like to avoid having an icon in the system tray / notification area.

If all else fails, I could always use the sliding notification from [Sliding Notification bar in java (a la Firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290210/sliding-notification-bar-in-java-a-la-firefox)

Comment: How to do the same using Libgdx?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might need a [translucent frame](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) without decorations.

Quick demo

OSX

[image]]

You can take advantage JLabel displays simple HTML

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;


/**
 * Simple demo on how a translucent window
 * looks like when is used to display the system clock.
 * @author <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/20654/oscarryz">Oscar Reyes</a>
 */
class Translucent extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    private final Date now = new Date();
    private final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    private final JLabel text = new JLabel();

    public Translucent() {
        super(true);
        timer.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        now.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        text.setText(String.format("<html><body><font size='50'>%s</font></body></html>",sdf.format(now)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        setTranslucency(f);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setBackground(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f / 3f));
        JPanel p =  new Translucent();
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Hola");
        l.setFont(new Font(l.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 128));
        p.add(l);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    // taken from: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/
    private static void setTranslucency( Window window){
        try {
               Class<?> awtUtilitiesClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
               Method mSetWindowOpacity = awtUtilitiesClass.getMethod("setWindowOpacity", Window.class, float.class);
               if (!mSetWindowOpacity.isAccessible()) {
                   mSetWindowOpacity.setAccessible(true);
               }
               mSetWindowOpacity.invoke(null, window, Float.valueOf(0.75f));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the nicest looking thing I've seen so far, so I'll go with it (-:
  It's too bad that there isn't (as far as I know) a way to use the native notifications from swing.

Comment: Java supports this now natively. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Comment: broken links @OscarRyz

Answer (score 15):

A standard way to do it is to use [Swing TrayIcon API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html). That would probably be the most convenient way too :)

Comment: At a guess, displayMessage will generate the style shown in the third screenshot.  On Windows, at any rate.

Comment: On my system, that ends up looking like this: http://i.imgur.com/tfTkv.png (I was hoping for something closer to the native gnome notification)

Comment: It is possible to create custom notification window, but it would be less "convenient". 

Basically it involves creating a window with FocusListener such that window closes when it loses focus. Obviously you will be able to do your own panting. For animation effects I would suggest Trident library found at http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used this, but [JToaster](http://jtoaster.sourceforge.net/) looks like it might be a good match.  Also, are you open to using SWT?  This might give you some additional options ([here's an example](http://hexapixel.com/2009/06/30/creating-a-notification-popup-widget)).

Comment: @Jeremy, you probably just need to work more with swing, it is very powerful ( when you get to know it, which btw, may take a while )

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend following library , it provides normal JFrame inside notification which gives full control .

http://jcarrierpigeon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It no longer exists