# How this pop up is called in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

[image]Friends I do not know how this pop up is called. I am developing a software that will use this kind of pop up. How this component is called in Java Swing? It would be helpful to get an example of this with sample code.

Comment: Swing is an entire (built-in) GUI library for Java, not just a popup.

Comment: That is a notification. Check this post:-  [How to create a notification in swing][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240415/how-to-create-a-notification-in-swing

Comment: You can customize JDialog according to you need by extending this class and i think using a JDialog box will be a better option here

Answer (score 2):

Use `JWindow / undecorated JDialog` for popup windows in Swing GUI