# System tray Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to display a tray notification using Java like the notifications that comes out in windows when disk space is low, there is no antivirus software etc.
[image]

Exactly like this.

Comment: [Java System Tray Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Comment: seems this is the same you are looking for, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240415/how-to-create-a-notification-in-swing

Comment: I am not looking for that mentioned here. I am trying just to display popup for some time and disappear. I am isn't it possible without manually creating frames and adding components...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm thinking maybe you should have a look at [TrayIcon.displayMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#displayMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType%29)

The only other way I know to achieve what you want, is via JNI

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Image img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TrayIcon ti = new TrayIcon(img, "Tooltip");
        try {
            // You need to add it to the system tray first
            SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(ti);
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        ti.displayMessage("Low Disk Space", "Diskspace is very low",
                MessageType.WARNING);

    }

});
```

Comment: didn't work in my system. I did this but didn't get the tray notification.

Comment: @KusumAdhikari what system are you on?

Comment: @KusumAdhikari Take a look at the updated example.  Then take a look at the tutorial that AnujKulkarni has suggested

Answer (score 5):

See this ->
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html