# How to receive push notification in a desktop application

Tags: java, push-notification

I am building an desktop app on Windows and I want to be able to receive push notification from my server. But as long as I search I can't find any way to do it (GCM, Window push, etc). I am developing my desktop app in Java with the `javaFX` library.

Is their a way to receive push from my server, something like a service worker like in Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox that I could implement in Java ?

The only way that I found is to do some GET each x minute on the server to see if there is a new message to display. But I don't think this is a good solution

Comment: you can use RabbitMQ, check [this](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/21/how-to-do-user-notifications-from-rabbitmq-messages/)

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240415/how-to-create-a-notification-in-swing    you can you swing in javaFx if the exact thing doesn't work for you