# Swing : Notification sliding out of taskbar

Tags: java, swing, notifications, taskbar, sliding

I'm looking for a way to have a notification sliding out of the taskbar.

Here is what I'm wanting :

[image: Outlook]

Hereunder is what I'd get with the **Swing** `TrayIcon`'s `displaymessage()` method but this is not what I'm looking for.

[image: TrayIcon]

There is certainly a way to make a message pane appear on the exact right bottom corner but I'm wanting it to be sliding like the ones you get using **Outlook**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240415/how-to-create-a-notification-in-swing or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290210/sliding-notification-bar-in-java-a-la-firefox .  Lots of example code and links to libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much @DanO ... Duplicating the post :)